# Euler formula. 100 faces

Tags: graph-theory

can  you give any clue to this task:
I have polyhedron with 100 faces, in which 50 are triangles and 50 rectangles. Prove that at least one of vertices has degree $\ge 5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We deduce the number of edges is half of the sum of the sides of the polygons, in this case this sum is $350$, so there are $175$ edges.

We now apply Euler's formula:

$V-E+F=2\implies V-175+100=2\implies V=77$.

So there are $77$ vertices and $175$ edges, therefore the sum of degrees is $350$ and the average vertex degree is $\frac{350}{77}\approx 4.55$. Your claim follows.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did the same, but got different numbers. Mistake in calc.

Comment: Sure, good job. I hope it helped :)